# SQL Query Logic Multiple Records

Tags: sql

I need to create a query to return rows where a Customer_ID has multiple Prospect_IDs associated with it. For example, I would like the query to be ale to return rows 2 and 3 below, since the Customer_ID is the same, but the Prospect_IDs are different, but NOT rows 5 and 6, since the Prospect_ids are the same:

```
Prospect_ID   Customer_ID
1001          31001
1002          31002
1003          31002
1004          31003
1005          31004
1005          31004
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us what SQL you've got so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 4):

To get the `Customer_id` with more than one distinct `Prospect_id`:

```
select customer_id
from yourtable
group by customer_id
having count(distinct prospect_id) >1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e16c9d/1)

If you want to return all of the details for those `Customer_Ids` then you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where exists (select customer_id
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
              group by customer_id
              having count(distinct prospect_id) >1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e16c9d/2).

This can also be written as (thanks [@ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube)):

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where exists (select customer_id
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
              and t1.prospect_id <> t2.prospect_id)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e16c9d/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select prospect_id, customer_id
from (select t.*,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by prospect_id, customer_id) as cnt_pc,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by customer_id) as cnt_c
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_pc <> cnt_c and cnt_c > 1
```